# how to add radiobutton for a category in editor part sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, moss, web-parts

how to add radiobutton for a category in editor part sharepoint?? 
for dropdownlist, textbox ,checkbox we can use enum,string or int,bool but if i want to add radiobutton,radiobuttonlist or any other control in a particular category then how can add it.?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.custompropertytoolpart.aspx

Answer (score 0):

By creating a custom toolpart you have complete control over how your toolpart behaves.

[Creating a Web Part with a Custom Tool Part](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd584178(office.11).aspx)